# How can I drive a controller spec for a nested route's new method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a fairly simple route setup:

```
  resources :users, only: [:show] do
    resources :account_groups
```

Which generates these routes:

```
$rake routes CONTROLLER=api/account_groups
    api_user_account_groups GET    /api/users/:user_id/account_groups(.:format)          api/account_groups#index
                            POST   /api/users/:user_id/account_groups(.:format)          api/account_groups#create
 new_api_user_account_group GET    /api/users/:user_id/account_groups/new(.:format)      api/account_groups#new
edit_api_user_account_group GET    /api/users/:user_id/account_groups/:id/edit(.:format) api/account_groups#edit
     api_user_account_group GET    /api/users/:user_id/account_groups/:id(.:format)      api/account_groups#show
                            PUT    /api/users/:user_id/account_groups/:id(.:format)      api/account_groups#update
                            DELETE /api/users/:user_id/account_groups/:id(.:format)      api/account_groups#destroy
```

The problem comes when I try to write a spec for `controller#new`:

```
describe '#new' do
  it 'responds 200' do
    get :new
    response.status.should eq 200
  end
end
```

It fails because the route needs to you specify `:user_id`:

```
1) Api::AccountGroupsController#new responds 200
     Failure/Error: get :new
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"api/account_groups", :action=>"new"}
```

But, when I do specify `:user_id`:

```
describe '#new' do
  it 'responds 200' do
    get :new, {user_id: user.id}
    response.status.should eq 200
  end
end
```

It complains that I've added an unexpected argument:

```
1) Api::AccountGroupsController#new responds 200
     Failure/Error: get :new, {user_id: user.id}
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Any idea how to make this work? Thanks!

Comment: Where is `user` defined in your spec?

Comment: `user` is defined at the top level as it's shared by all of the specs. If `user` were undefined, you'd get a `NameError` rather than an `ArgumentError`.

Comment: I was wondering how it is defined more than where. :) Did you get any stacktrace at all?

Comment: Whats the name of your test class?

Comment: `class Api::AccountGroupsController` and `describe Api::AccountGroupsController do`

Answer (score 0):

The name of your test class should be:

`Api::Users::AccountGroupsControllerTest`

Comment: That's just throwing an `UninitializedConstant` error. I tried renaming the controller too but no love.